# Can CSS morph images by pixel mapping?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I'd like to be able to animate the transition between these 2 images, which don't have perfect pixel-to-pixel mapping (so I'd like to specify the key pixels myself):

[image: 1996 to 2016]

Can something like this be accomplished with CSS (or, failing that, javascript)? I know CSS3 can transition basic shapes (e.g. https://www.w3.org/Talks/2012/0416-CSS-WWW2012/Demos/transitions/demo-transitions-1.html) but I'd like to do the same with a pair of images that are similar but different (e.g. in age of the face or building).

Comment: I don’t know enough about SVG to offer any kind of an answer, but I think this is something that SVG is probably better at than CSS. That, or using canvas and JavaScript.

Comment: But with Svg wouldn’t the input graphics need to be vector based rather than raster based? I want to animate transitions between photos.

Comment: I honestly don’t know; I’d guess so, given the name, but given the SVG elements can have background images I think they can accept raster images. Though obviously that loses some of the point of the format.

Comment: You could re-create JavaScript morphing, or take a look at something like: https://github.com/jembezmamy/morpher-js (demo: http://jembezmamy.github.io/morpher-js/demos.html)

Comment: That Javascript solution looks promising (feel free to post as an answer so you can get proper credit). Maybe the term is "easing" for images. The SVG I will do some more research, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can only do the cool transformational stuff because it's working on markup, even if it's SVG. It can't grab individual pixel data.

(I think it's a great question and I'd love to cite something, but I would have to cite something about what CSS *can't* do... which is what this post will be after long enough....)

Comment: I can believe that. Thankfully javascript makes for a good fallback when CSS can't accomplish 2D graphics challenges.